# get all transitive relationships from a node via cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Do you know how to write a cypher query that would return all the transitive relationships related to a node.

For instance if I have : `(node1)-[rel1]->(node2)-[rel2]->(node3)`.

I'd like a query that, given `node1` returns `rel1` and `rel2`.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a variable path match, assuming your start node is node 1 having label `Label` and `name='node1'`:

```
MATCH path=(node1:Label {name:'node1'})-[*..100]->()
RETURN relationships(path) as rels
```

The `relationships` function returns a list holding all relationships along that path. It is a best practice to provide an upper limit to variable depth matches, here I've set it arbitrarily to 100.

### update regarding comment below

To get the id's of the relationships:

```
MATCH path=(node1:Label {name:'node1'})-[*..100]->()
RETURN [r in relationships(path) | ID(x)] as relIds
```

Comment: thanks for your help ! I have an additional question :p Do you know a way to retrieve the ids of these relationships ? Thx